# Does setting accessibilityElementsHidden work recursively?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Simple question: if I set `accessibilityElementsHidden` on a `UIViewController`, will it automatically hide everything in all of its views, and their subviews, etc.?

I’m turning `accessibilityElementsHidden` on for some views, and they’re still showing up in my VoiceOver elements as I swipe through. I’ve ensured that I’m posting a `LayoutChanged` notification after doing so, and I’m implementing all three of the `UIAccessibilityContainer` informal protocol methods, and verified that my `accessibilityElements` property does NOT contain those views. Yet, they still show up as I swipe through :(

Comment: if I understand the Apple's Documentations like [UIAccessibilityElement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityElement_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAccessibilityElement/initWithAccessibilityContainer:) right, `UIAccessibilityElements` can't be views because `UIView`s are accessible by default ("_In general, you do not create accessibility elements for items in your application because standard UIKit controls and views are accessible by default._")

Comment: @anneblue `UIAccessibilityElement` is a generic implementation of the `UIAccessibility` protocol. `UIView` also implements the protocol (in fact, it's declared on `NSObject`). Any object implementing the protocol is referred to as an "accessibility element."

Comment: As I understand it; accessibilityElementsHidden only affects the *subviews* of a given view; and I suspect it doesn't work on UIViewController at all - only actual views in that controller's current view tree. Have you tried setting isAccessibilityElement=NO on the views you're trying to hide? - that's the usual way to hide specific UIViews. Curious, why are you implementing UIAccessibilityContainer - are you doing it to expose custom non-view UI elements, or is it part of trying to hide these other views?

Answer (score 3):

> I’m turning accessibilityElementsHidden on for some views, and they’re
>   still showing up […]

Make sure that `accessibilityElementsHidden` is set to `YES` on the *parent* of the elements you would like to hide.

Comment: Yup, I'm turning it on on both the view controller and its .view property. No joy :(

Comment: Can you share the view and accessibility hierarchies?

Comment: Note that setting this property to true on the parent will end up hiding *all* that parent's subviews; which may not be appropriate if you only want to hide one of several siblings.